# generic class with an arraylist containing reference of generic class itself

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, generic-programming

```
class Node<T>{

private T myValue;
private ArrayList<Object> next;



public <U> void addLink(U n){
        this.next.add(n);
}


}
```

in main i have:

```
    Node<String> myNode1 = new Node<String>("Ciao");
    Node<Integer> myNode2 = new Node<Integer>(12);

    myNode1.addLink(myNode2, true);
```

I need next in class Node to cointain pointers to the adiacent node

but java throws NullPointerException

Please help me.

Comment: Is myNode1.next actually set to a reference, or is it still null?

Comment: Also you can look at the stacktrace that java outputs with this error. It'll tell you exactly where the null pointer occured.

Answer (score 4):

`this.next` never got initialized. Try declaring it:

```
private ArrayList<Object> next = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

Comment: Yes, although I think `ArrayList<Object>` is bad form in most circumstances. I suspect user496223 would be better off with an `ArrayList<Node<?>>`

Comment: Or maybe even `Node<T>` given the name of the `next` field.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not exactly clear on what he had in mind with this. It almost looks like each node could potentially have a different type of object in it, which seems odd to me.